# Organic Chemistry - Effect of methyl substituent in Aromatic Substitution via Benzyne

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, nucleophilic-substitution

[image: Image 1]

The following reaction has been taken from my study material. This shows that the benzene ring is undergoing a nucleophilic aromatic substitution via benzyne mechanism (presence of a strong base like $\ce{NaNH2}$). My question is:

**Why is substitution preferred at the ortho position?**

The following [link](https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2018/09/17/nucleophilic-aromatic-substitution-2-benzyne/) explains the mechanism quite well and gives an example of ortho-chlorotoluene undergoing a similar reaction. Since both proceed via the same benzyne intermediate, why is there a difference in the products formed by meta-chlorotoluene? Or is my study material wrong in saying that o-aminotoluene is a major product? Any help regarding this is appreciated!

Attaching the related reaction's image:
[image]

Comment: I am not sure though but maybe the -NH2 group at ortho may stabilise more the hyperconjugative structures of the product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Me group has no directing effect in the deprotonation so there are 2 protons (*o* & *p*) that can be removed with equal probability by the NaNH2 to give the benzyne. These give 2 possible benzynes (2 and 3 relative to Me). The nucleophile will add with equal facility to either end of either benzyne giving a mixture of 3 isomers in 1:2:1 ratio. The major isomer is the *m*- aminotoluene because it can arise from both of the possible benzynes.

Comment: Ok that makes a lot of sense. So that means that m-aminotoluene and not o-aminotoluene is the major product, which means that the first reaction is wrong.